# Using MS LogParser to enumerate login events

Tags: xml, xpath, logparser

I'm trying to use MS Log Parser v2.2 to enumerate login events on an XML log exported from a Windows 7 Professional Security Log.

```
C:\>LogParser -rootXPath:/Events/Event -fNames:XPath "SELECT /Event/System/TimeCreated/@SystemTime, /Event/EventData/Data/[@Name='TargetUserName'] FROM log.xml WHERE /Event/System/EventID = 4624" -i:xml
Error: Syntax Error: <from-clause>: expecting FROM keyword instead of token '='TargetUserName']'
```

I expect the output to be something like this:

```
/Events/Event/System/TimeCreated/@SystemTime /Events/Event/EventData/Data/@Name='TargetUserName'
-------------------------------------------- ----------------------------
2016-11-18T16:29:02.849055000Z               username
```

But instead, I get an XPath expression error.

```
Error: Syntax Error: <from-clause>: expecting FROM keyword instead of token '='TargetUserName']'
```

Can anybody help me understand what the correct syntax is to get this information from LogParser?

Comment: I know nothing about LogParser, but I'm sure the 2nd XPath in your SELECT has invalid syntax. The predicate need an element context to be applied to, its either `Data` : `/Event/EventData/Data[@Name='TargetUserName']`, or maybe any child element of `Data` : `/Event/EventData/Data/*[@Name='TargetUserName']`

Comment: On tip of har07's suggestion, I'm quite sure LogParser is being thrown off by the single quotes in your XPath. Try to escape them, the LogParser help should explain how.

Comment: LogParser does understand `/Event/EventData/Data/@Name`, but gives an error on `/Event/EventData/Data[@Name]`. So I think the attribute reference syntax is correct for LogParser. (I do not disagree that it is non-standard) The corresponding XML is `<Data Name='TargetUserName'>`